# Accessing dynamically added controls on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the dynamic `Control` that caused a postback.  All `Controls` are added dynamically to a `Panel`.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel"></asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

I have read that the two following methods should find the postback `Control` (at this point I am not concerned with `Buttons` causing a postback, but will be).

```
private Control GetPostBackControl()
            {
            Control toReturn = null;
            string controlName = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
            {
                toReturn = RecurseControls(this.Page, controlName);
            }
           return toReturn;
    }

 private Control RecurseControls(Control root, String toFind)
        {
            String s = root.UniqueID;
            if (root.UniqueID == toFind)
            {
                return root;
            }
            foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
            {
                Control t = RecurseControls(c, toFind);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    return t;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

When stepping through the debugger, the recursion finds the panel, but there are no child `Controls` within it. I'm assuming that my understanding of how these methods work was initially off, and they cannot find dynamically added `Controls` before they are recreated for this `Post`. If this is the case, is there another way to find the dynamic `Control` that triggered the postback?  If not, is there a way to cause the page to re-post within a `Control's` `EventHandler`?

Please note that I am using a master page.  Whether I use the recursive method as I have posted it, or like `RecurseControls(this.Master, toFind);` I still don't see the `Panel's` child `Controls`.  `GetPostBackControl()` is also called within `Page_Init()`.

Comment: I find dynamically created controls to be a real mess, particularly if you ever post back the page.  Consider not doing that and using entirely static controls (controls like `DataGrid` and `Repeater` can be used to represent an unknown amount of data).  From personal experience, it's *much* easier to do that than try to deal with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing controls added programmatically on postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763050/accessing-controls-added-programmatically-on-postback)

Comment: Dynmically created controls need to be re-created on **every** request, including postbacks. ASP.NET will not automatically do this for you.

Comment: I would love to have everything predefined and just mess with the Visible property or use a DataGrid.  But, it is unknown exactly what user controls are added/deleted in what order, or how many there will be - it is all based on user input.  Also, the user controls are recreated in the Page_Init, but new user controls need to be added/deleted based on the control that caused the postback. This is why I was trying to use these two methods prior to recreation.

Comment: Maybe I could use something like a Repeater to have the same effect, but I'm unfamiliar with that control.  I'll do some reading on it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In general, dynamically added controls will need to be re-added on each server round trip. The exception are control content of controls that maintain ViewState. Insure that your controls are added during PageInit which occurs before ViewState is loaded.

Then you can simply reference your controls to acquire their contents, values, selected indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find the values entered on any of the controls added dynamically, you can always find those values by simply accessing the `Request.Params` collection.  For example, if you dynamically add an TextBox control with name "MyTextBox", when the page posts back, regardless of how the control was added, the Request.Params["MyTextBox"] will have the value inputted by the user; again, provided you assign a name to the control.

Quick example:

```
TextBox b= null;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
      b=new TextBox();
      b.ID="textbox"+i;
      //asp.net will assign the name the same as the ID of the element
      placeHolder.Controls.Add(b); //placeHolder is the container for all dynamically-added controls
}
```

When the page posts back, you can get, for example, the value entered on "textbox1" as so:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    Response.Write(Request.Params["textbox1"]);
}
```

Finally, iterating recursively to find a control is incredibly inefficient. The performance degrades exponentially as more controls are added to the page. With care, one can almost always find a control in O(1) or at least O(n) if you structure your page carefully and instead of searching through the whole page, you only search through the parent container.

Comment: This is great info I didn't know about, and I can definitely use it for this project.  Unfortunately, I just need the control that caused the postback for most of what is being done.  Thank you for the suggestion!